# Call objective c method from java script function to get url

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I set `video.ma` as my "URL Schema" in main iOS project. I get the total `url` from browser using this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    NSLog(@"Tulon %@", url);

    if (!url)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    // calls into javascript global function 'handleOpenURL'
    NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"handleOpenURL(\"%@\");", url];
    [self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    // all plugins will get the notification, and their handlers will be called
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification object:url]];

    return YES;
}
```

I put this method in App delegate and It do redirect me into my App from browser if I try to enter the upper `url` (`video.ma`) in browser. I can get the `url` by `NSLog`.

Now, This is my js function in js.file:

```
function handleOpenURL(url)
{
      // TODO: parse the url, and do something
      document.write(url);

}
```

But it is not getting the following `url`. What's wrong I did?

Comment: why do you want to do this ? I guess you wanted to open the url in the native browser .

Comment: Thanks for commenting. No, I have to pass the url to the `.js` file. Any way's I got my answer. My javascript developer declare the js function in local not in global. That's why it wasn't working. From my perspective the code is all good. Have a good day dear.